Roblox script to move camera back to default not working, tried many things but no one can seem to figure it out
My roblox script for moving the camera back to the default when you load up a new baseplate isn't working. there are only 2 scripts that mess with the camera. a localscript with the contents:
script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
    player.Team = game.Teams[script.Parent.Parent.TextLabel.Text]
    player.PlayerGui.teamSelect.Enabled = false

    local cam = workspace.CurrentCamera
    local char = player.Character or player.CharacterAdded:Wait()

    cam.CameraType = Enum.CameraType.Fixed
    cam.CameraSubject = char.Head
end)

and another with the contents:
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local cam = workspace.CurrentCamera
repeat cam.CameraType = Enum.CameraType.Scriptable wait() until cam.CameraType == Enum.CameraType.Scriptable
cam.CFrame = workspace.camPositions[script.Parent.TextLabel.Text.."Cam"].CFrame

I tried many large Ai bots, searched the internet for too long, and nothing worked.

Please specify what you are trying to exactly achieve. By moving the camera back to the default do you mean back to the Player's Character?

To reset the camera to the default you should set the CameraType to Custom and the CameraSubject to the character's humanoid.
 cam.CameraType = Enum.CameraType.Custom
 cam.CameraSubject = char:FindFirstChildOfClass("Humanoid")

